# Mongodb findone query in node.js & express times out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to find one user in a db where password and username matches. If I write the correct username and password everything works smoothly. But if I write the wrong password for instance I get a timeout after about one minute.

Any suggestions of how I could fix this?

```
exports.bsLogin = function(req, res) {
console.log('************ bslogin ************');
var body = req.body;
var username2 = body.username;
var password2 = body.password;
db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
    collection.findOne({username:username2, password:password2}, function(err, item) {
        if (err) { 
            res.render('bslogin',
                { title : 'Hello', error : 'Username or Password is incorrect' }
            );
            return;
        }
        if (item) {
            res.writeHead(302, {
                'Location': '/backstageArea'
            });
            res.end();
        }
    });
});
};
```

Comment: You aren't provided a response when there is neither an `err` nor an `item`. Add an `else` or `if (!err && !item)` block.

Comment: @jonathan-lonowski thanks. That did it. Would you like to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's timing out because no response is being given when there is neither an `err` nor an `item`.

Based on the current responses, the 1st `if` could probably be modified to handle both MongoDB errors and lack of items:

```
if (err || !item) {
    res.render('bslogin',
        { title : 'Hello', error : 'Username or Password is incorrect' }
    );
    return;
}
```

Or, add an `else` block to respond to each scenario separately:

```
if (err) {
    /* ... */
} else if (item) {
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* ... */
}
```